# Adding new locale in Enfinity Intershop

Tags: e-commerce, enfinity, intershop

I am trying to add a new `Locale` to one of the catalog in Enfinity Intershop 6.2, but I am not able to achieve that. This is what I tried so far:

1) Updated the localization properties to include the new locale, as below:

```
french = fr FR EUR false
```

2) Added the new locale entry in SwitchLocale.isml and rebuilt the catalog. The updated SwitchLocale.isml files looks as below:

```
<!--- TEMPLATENAME: SwitchLocale.isml --->
<iscontent charset="UTF-8">
<ismodule template = "inc/ShowLocaleItem.isml"
name="ShowLocaleItem"
attribute="LocaleID"
attribute="Flag"
>
<isif condition="#CurrentSession:URLLanguageID NE 'en_US'#">
   <ISShowLocaleItem LocaleID="en_US" Flag="flag_en.gif">
</isif>
<isif condition="#CurrentSession:URLLanguageID NE 'fr_FR'#">
   <ISShowLocaleItem LocaleID="fr_FR" Flag="flag_fr.gif">
</isif>
```

3) Added the `flag_fr.gif` in `branding` and updated the `branding` package.
4) Cleared the `Page Caching` from administration and restarted the `Intershop Enfinity Application server`

The Problem:
If I enter the URL as usually, like `www.abc.com` (which is then redirected to `www.abc.com\en-EN\index.html`, as English is the default locale) then it doesn't show the new flag that was added (`flag_fr.gif`). However, after that if I change the URL to `www.abc.com\fr-FR\index.html` then it shows the web page in French language properly.

Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

-Edited-
Have you removed the  localization.lastupdate file from (SHARE)/system/config/cluster and restarted the server? Otherwise the new locale won't be read and applied to the db.
Adding a new locale requires expensive operations on the DB (adding columns and other), so, after he applies the changes, the application server generates a file called .lastupdate. The next time the server startup, if it finds the lastupdate file, just ignores the properties file.
If you remove the lastupdate file, you'll force the app server to re-read the properties file and change the db. After that, you'all see that a new lastupdate will be recreated.

The same mechanism applies for taxes and few other configuration properties, up to ISH 7.2 I believe.

Comment: This would have served better as a comment. Your Rep is currently too low to comment, so I would suggest editing your answer to show a full explanation of your suggestion - what it does, why it needs to happen and how to do this step by step. That way, your answer would count as a legitimate solution for new users to potentially try out.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - it's very helpful in this regard!